Mapping Container Users to Host Users with Podman
I'm still learning containers so please bare with me. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around some things.
I'm setting up a rootful container that needs persistent storage and rwx access to a folder on a host system. Like so:
--volume=/host/example:/container/example
Let's say the service inside of the the container runs as user foo. To my understanding, there is no secure way to do this without some form of UID remapping. Because the foo user does not exist outside of the container, you need to use "other" permissions and you would never want to set those to rwx i.e. d 0777 /host/example.
Even if you could set the permissions of /host/example to 1000:1000 (and I don't know if that would work or not), it's still may not a good solution because then only the default user on the host has access to the data. And you also can't modify the UID of the user in the container because that would break all the permissions needed to run the service in the first place.
So, we create a user foo in the host with UID:GID of 989:989 for example. And we map the UID to the user in the container like so:
--uidmap=1000:989
--gidmap=1000:989

But this does not work. This container needs access to my NVIDIA drivers and for some reason, you need to map root to something as well or nvidia-container-toolkit throws an error:
conmon[3523966]: conmon <nwarn>: runtime stderr: error executing hook `/nix/store/cnkyyycyfiws224mkhf42hrm6kyvggxw-container-toolkit-container-toolkit-1.15.0-rc.3/bin/nvidia-ctk` (exit code: 1)
{"msg":"error executing hook `/nix/store/cnkyyycyfiws224mkhf42hrm6kyvggxw-container-toolkit-container-toolkit-1.15.0-rc.3/bin/nvidia-ctk` (exit code: 1)","level":"error","time":"2024-11-26T23:04:03.632243Z"}

It's possible this is just a NixOS bug though, I'm not sure.
The only solution I have found is to simply map the container root to the host root.
--uidmap=0:0
--gidmap=0:0
--uidmap=1000:989
--gidmap=1000:989

But I can't imagine this being a very secure solution because if the container is compromised, the container root will also own the host root which invalidates the sandboxing.
So what exactly is the best/most secure way to do this?
My nixos config:
comfyui = {
  image = "docker.io/obeliks/comfyui:latest-cu121";
  autoStart = true;
  labels = {
    "io.containers.autoupdate" = "registry";
  };
  ports = [ "8188:8188" ];
  environment = {
    HF_HOME = "/cache/huggingface/hub";
    COMFYUI_PATH = "/app";
    COMFYUI_MODEL_PATH = "/app/models";
    COMFYUI_EXTRA_ARGS = "--lowvram;
  };
  volumes = [
    "/export/ai/images:/app/output" #permissions hell
    ...
  ];
  extraOptions = [
    "--name=comfyui"
    "--gpus=all"
    #"--uidmap=0:0"
    #"--gidmap=0:0"
    #"--uidmap=1000:989"
    #"--gidmap=1000:989"
  ];
};


Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating your image setup?  Many images don't actually care what user they run as: one common enough setup is for the application files to be owned by root and world-readable but not writable, so any non-root user can run the application but not modify it.  The common (Docker-on-plain-Linux) case is that docker run -u $(id -u) is enough.

Sure, I've added my nix config for the container. With this setup the host user running it is always root. It does indeed work settings user = "root";, (equivalent of -u 0), but the container I am using was built to use the comfyui user and it doesn't have consistent "other" permissions.
